# ValueError: 0 is not in list in python

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

I am trying to return a list of tuples sorted with the mosr similar candidate to the question and the index of that candidate in the orignal list of candidates:
I implemented this function:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def rank_candidates(question, candidates, embeddings, dim=300):
    """
        question: a string
        candidates: a list of strings (candidates) which we want to rank
        embeddings: some embeddings
        dim: dimension of the current embeddings

        result: a list of pairs (initial position in the list, question)
    """
    cosi_dic={}
    most_candidates=[]
    q_vec=question_to_vec(question,embeddings,dim)
    for i in candidates:
      can_vec=question_to_vec(i,embeddings,dim)

      cosi_dic[cosine_similarity(can_vec.reshape(1,-1),  q_vec.reshape(1,-1))[0][0]]=i
    for i in (list(reversed(sorted(cosi_dic.keys(),)))):
      most_candidates.append((candidates.index(cosi_dic[i]),cosi_dic[i]))
    return most_candidates
```

and the functions `question_to_vec` is a function used to get the mean of all words embeddings vectors in the sentence here it is the function:

```
def question_to_vec(question, embeddings, dim=300):
    """
        question: a string
        embeddings: dict where the key is a word and a value is its' embedding
        dim: size of the representation

        result: vector representation for the question
    """
    v=np.zeros(dim)
    all_vectors=[]
    question=question.split()
    for i in question:
      if i in embeddings:
        all_vectors.append(embeddings[i])
    if all_vectors:
      v=np.mean(all_vectors, axis=0)
    return v
```

the expected output should be something like that: [(2,c),(0,b),(1,a)] if c is the most similar with index two in the input list candidate and a being the least similar. However, when I tried to run this code:

```
wv_ranking = []
for i in range(len(validation)):
    line=validation[i]
    q, *ex = line
    ranks = rank_candidates(q, ex, wv_embeddings)
    wv_ranking.append([r[0] for r in ranks].index(0) + 1)
```

where is `wv_embeddings` is the embbeddings by GoogleNews-vectors-negative300, 
I got the error: `ValueError: 0 is not in list`
I tried to check the cosine similary between the line which got the exception and found out that all elements have value of zero?

Comment: not possible to solve without seeing the implementation of all used functions

Comment: which functions?

Comment: provide a minimal reproducible example, right now question_to_vec, cosine_similarity, validation, wv_embeddings are not defined

Answer (score 0):

After digging more into the error, found out that using dictionary while processing the data in the function resulted in replacing the values which have the same cosine similairty value. so the function should be like the following:

```
def rank_candidates(question, candidates, embeddings, dim=300):
    """
        question: a string
        candidates: a list of strings (candidates) which we want to rank
        embeddings: some embeddings
        dim: dimension of the current embeddings

        result: a list of pairs (initial position in the list, question)
    """
    #cosi_dic={}
    most_candidates=[]
    updated_most_candidates=[]
    q_vec=question_to_vec(question,wv_embeddings,300)
    for i in candidates:
 # print(type(i))
      can_vec=question_to_vec(i,wv_embeddings,300)

      #cosi_dic[cosine_similarity(can_vec.reshape(1,-1),  q_vec.reshape(1,-1))[0][0]]=i
      sim=cosine_similarity(can_vec.reshape(1,-1),  q_vec.reshape(1,-1))[0][0]
    #for i in (list(reversed(sorted(cosi_dic.keys(),)))):
      #most_candidates.append((candidates.index(cosi_dic[i]),cosi_dic[i]))
      most_candidates.append((sim,i))
    most_candidates.sort(key=lambda x: x[0],reverse=True)
    for i in most_candidates:
      updated_most_candidates.append((candidates.index(i[1]),i[1]))


    return updated_most_candidates
```